# Making a python dictionary from a huge textfile?

Tags: python

I have a textfile like this separated by tab:

```
20001   World Economies
20002   Bill Clinton
20004   Internet Law
20005   Philipines Elections
20006   Israel Politics
20008   Golf
20009   Music
20010   Disasters
```

It is a huge file consisting of 100 such pairs. How can I make a dictionary in python using this file?

```
def get_pair(line):
  key, sep, value = line.strip().partition("\t")
  return int(key), value


with open("TopicMapped.txt") as fd:    
           d = dict(get_pair(line) for line in fd)

fd=open('dictionary.txt', 'w')
print>> fd,d
```

However, printing this dictionary to a file gives me an empty file?

Comment: What's the code for your `get_pair` function?

Comment: my bad. Added it in the question

Comment: If I try that, I get a set of tuples. You'd probably have to use something like `d = dict(get_pair(line)[0]: get_pair[1] for line in fd)` which would mean that you call get_pair twice, so makes little sense.

Comment: Just to clarify for future queries, a file with `100` key/value pairs is **not** a *huge file*. Additionally, for that kind of tabular data, I would suggest using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you are going to process it somehow later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this using the following, simple code:

```
fID=open('TopicMapped.txt')

myDict=dict() #init empty dictionary

for line in fID:
    #read the file line-by-line (if it's huge, it might be cumbersome to import it entirely in memory, e.g. using readlines())
    # and also remove newline tags
    line=line.rstrip()

    #create a list where the first element is the number and the second element is the text
    line=line.split("\t")

    #update dictionary
    myDict[line[0]]=line[1]

print myDict
fID.close()
```

And this code returns the following dictionary

```
{'20010': 'Disasters', '20006': 'Israel Politics', '20005': 'Philipines Elections', '20004': 'Internet Law', '20002': 'Bill Clinton', '20001': 'World Economies', '20009': 'Music', '20008': 'Golf'}
```

If you want the number to be integer and not string, you can do something like

```
myDict[int(line[0])]=line[1] #update dictionary
```

And the resulting dictionary will be

```
{20001: 'World Economies', 20002: 'Bill Clinton', 20004: 'Internet Law', 20005: 'Philipines Elections', 20006: 'Israel Politics', 20008: 'Golf', 20009: 'Music', 20010: 'Disasters'}
```

Comment: I am not sure why but on trying the code out, the output I receive is : {20001: 'World Economies\r20002'} and it stops there

Comment: I have formatted the input .txt as follows: <number><tab><string><a capo>.

Comment: I too have <number><tab><string> but what is <a capo>?

Comment: newline. I also left a newline after the last line of the txt

Comment: when I use the myDict[int(line[0])]=line[1], the dictionary comes well printed with the <number><tab><string><newline> format but using the myDict[line[0]]=line[1], I get all the /r and /t again

Comment: That's actually weird. As you can see I printed both cases without strange tags. By the way, I'm using PyCharm as IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Your own code actually works, it looks like it gives you an empty file because you are testing the file before you have closed it:

```
In [15]: fd=open('dictionary.txt', 'w')

In [16]: print >> fd, d
# looks empty
In [17]: cat dictionary.txt 
# actually close the file so what is in the buffer is written to disk
In [18]: fd.close()
# now you see the data
In [19]: cat dictionary.txt
{20001: '  World Economies', 20002: '  Bill Clinton', 20004: '  Internet Law', 20005: '  Philipines Elections', 20006: '  Israel Politics', 20008: '  Golf', 20009: '  Music', 20010: '  Disasters'}
```

You can do it with a *dict comprehension* and also use `with` oo open your files and it will automatically close them for you avoiding simple errors like the code above:

```
In [7]: with open("text.txt") as f:
            dct = {int(k): v.rstrip() for line in f for k, v  in (line.split(None, 1),)}
   ...:     

In [8]: dct
Out[8]: 
{20001: 'World Economies',
 20002: 'Bill Clinton',
 20004: 'Internet Law',
 20005: 'Philipines Elections',
 20006: 'Israel Politics',
 20008: 'Golf',
 20009: 'Music',
 20010: 'Disasters'}
```

If you are storing in a file use the `json` module:

```
In [13]: import json

In [14]: with open("text.txt") as f, open("out.json","w") as out:
            json.dump({int(k): v.rstrip() for line in f for k, v  in (line.split(None, 1),)}, out)
   ....:     

In [15]: cat out.json
{"20001": "World Economies", "20002": "Bill Clinton", "20004": "Internet Law", "20005": "Philipines Elections", "20006": "Israel Politics", "20008": "Golf", "20009": "Music", "20010": "Disasters"}
```

json will always parse the ints as strings so if you really want ints you could `pickle` your dict:

```
In [8]: import pickle

In [9]: with open("text.txt") as f, open("out.pkl","wb") as out:
            pickle.dump({int(k): v.rstrip() for line in f for k, v  in (line.split(None, 1),)}, out)
   ...:     

In [10]: with open("out.pkl","rb") as in_fle:
            dct = pickle.load(in_fle)
   ....:     

In [11]: dct
Out[11]: 
{20001: 'World Economies',
 20002: 'Bill Clinton',
 20004: 'Internet Law',
 20005: 'Philipines Elections',
 20006: 'Israel Politics',
 20008: 'Golf',
 20009: 'Music',
 20010: 'Disasters'}
```

You can also use the [*`csv`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) lib to do the parsing:

```
import csv
with open("text.txt") as f:
        dct = {int(k): v for k,v in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")}
```

Comment: How is your output so neat and presentable? I am not sure why but I receive something like this: {20001: 'World Economies\r20002\tBill Clinton\r20004\tInternet Law\r20005\tPhilipines Elections\r20006\tIsrael Politics\r20008\tGolf\r20009\tMusic\r20010\tDisasters\r20011\tBill Clinton\r20012\tReligion\r20013\tOlympics\}

Comment: @minks,  ipython pretty-prints your dicts for you, it makes it a lot easier to read large dicts. If you don't use it I would suggest getting it http://ipython.org/,